# How to check whether user is logged in or not from controller in Token Based Authentication using MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

I have `ActonResult Data()` in `HomeController`, I want to show **Data.cshtml** the only user already logged in. otherwise, it will return **LogoutView.cshtml** page

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult Data()
    {
        bool isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        if(isAuthenticated)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View("LogoutView");
        }
    }
```

I am using Token Based Authentication in MVC5.

> 1. I can do LogIn without any issues.
> 2. Before I do login, I tried to go **http://localhost/Poject1/home/data**, It shows **LogoutView.cshtml** as I expect.
> 3. After I logged in, I tried to visit the same link **http://localhost/Poject1/home/data**, It shows **Data.cshtml** as I expect also.
> 4. But I do logged out used below code, then I tried to visit **http://localhost/Poject1/home/data**, But it still shows **Data.cshtml**

```
<input id="btnLogout" type="button" value="Logout" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnLogout').click(function () {
            console.log('Get Token = '+sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken'))
            sessionStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
            console.log('After remove Token = ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken'))   // it print null
        });
    })
</script>
```

**Login Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSignIn').click(function () {
            var loginData = {
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: $('#txtSignInEmail').val(),
                password: $('#txtSignInPassword').val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Token',
                data: loginData
            }).done(function (data) {

                console.log('Username =='+data.userName);

                $('#user').text(data.userName)
                $('#UserName').text(JSON.stringify(data.userName));
                // Cache the access token in session storage.
                console.log('Login Success');
                sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.access_token);
            }).fail(function (showError) {
                $('#signInError').text(JSON.stringify(showError));
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Because you are removing the key from your sessionStorage using javascript on the client side, the server doesn't know if the user is logged out. You will have to call a controller action method in `$('#btnLogout').click` and sign out the user on the server.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal So how can I do it?.

Comment: Please edit your question to share the code for your login method.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal Can you check my update now?..

Comment: we need your server-side login method, please.

Comment: Can you just get the userId: 'User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()'? If userId is valid it means user is logged in...

Answer (score 0):

[you can use Autherize Filter on controller level as well as you use this filter on Action Level. you can also customize it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gQQ9.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please elaborate your answer and use proper formatting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer